# Angular ng-cloak in with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, angular, thymeleaf

I am coding a dropzone with angular frontend, using Spring server as backend. I want to use the ng-cloak directive:

```
<body ng-controller="fileCtrl" ng-cloak>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <div class="well">
            <form action="" class="dropzone" dropzone="" id="dropzone">
                <div class="dz-default dz-message">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload File</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="reset()">Reset Dropzone</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form>
                <label>File to download</label>
                <input ng-model="filename" type="text" placeholder="Filename" />
                <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-href="{{ partialDownloadLink + filename }}">Download File</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Load Angular scripts-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.17/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fileAppControllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fileAppDirectives.js"></script>

    <!-- Load Dropzone JS -->
    <script src="js/dropzone/dropzone.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    </script>

</body>
```

The problem is that if I use ng-cloak directive, the body dissappears.
If I remove the display:none; line from inspector in browser, the body appears but when drop the file into the input area, it flicker the file.

---

**SOLVED**

I forgot put in the html tag "ng-app="fileApp"".

Comment: how is this spring or java related?

Comment: I am using java as backend.

Comment: you are usually drinking fluids, doesn't make it coca-cola related. a "flickering" on your screen, is a front-end issue, not back-end

Comment: Java 8, Spring Boot 2.0

Comment: seeing as what you describe is an angular issue, how is that relevant?

Comment: Thanks for replying. do not know if this is generating some problem in my dropzone and I think is a necessary information.

Comment: I edited my question cause is related only to frontend. Thanks

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.